# Is it possible to update a TFS task whenever an artefact is uploaded into TFS-Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, tfs

We use TFS integrated with Sharepoint for storing artefacts. Examples: end user documentation.

The artifacts are uploaded using Visual studio 2010 and not from web interface.

For each artefact preparation, there will be a task created in TFS.

Example:
Documentation preparation

The requirement is whenever a document is uploaded or modified in the sharepoint folder, can the user be alerted?

Example: 
which TFS task he/she needs to update the completed hours

FOlder structure:

similar to the one shown in the 2nd answer to the below question

[Share project documents in TFS different ways, what are your best practices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845460/share-project-documents-in-tfs-different-ways-what-are-your-best-practices)

Answer (score 0):

It's not there by default, but one could build it oneself using a ListItemEventHandler (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms437502.aspx) in sharepoint or a custom aproval workflow that activates from within sharepoint and creates workitems in TFS using the object model (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130322.aspx).

> The requirement is whenever a document is uploaded or modified in the
>   sharepoint folder, can the user be alerted?

A simpler way to achieve only this requirement might be to put an sharepoint alert on the document list so one would recieve an e-mail when an item is created.